# Open emailclient from Adobe Air with attachment and htmltext

Tags: air, adobe

Is there a way to open your e-mailclient from adobe air with mail attachment or else with a prefilled htmltext?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can add an attachment like this.

You can prefill subject, body, cc, etc - e.g.

```
import flash.net.*;

public function mailto():void{
         var htmlstr:String = '<b>test</b>';
     var url = "mailto:dinesh@dinesh.co.za?subject=test&body="+htmlstr; 
     var urlReq = new URLRequest(url); 
     navigateToURL(urlReq);
}
```

Comment: yes i know thanks. But what i really wanted to to was to add a attachment to the email.